# interacting with a CMutex without MFC

Tags: qt, mfc

We have multiple MFC apps, which use CMutex( false, "blah" ), where "blah" allows the mutex to work across process boundaries.

One of these apps was re-written without MFC (using Qt instead).  How can I simulate the CMutex using Win32 calls? (Qt's QMutex is not inter-process.)  I prefer not to modify the MFC apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For inter-process mutexes you want these calls:

> [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411(VS.85).aspx)
>
> [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032(VS.85).aspx)
>
> [ReleaseMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685066(VS.85).aspx)
>
> [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211(VS.85).aspx)

These are the underlying Win32 API calls that CMutex is a wrapper around.

For in-process only mutexes you can also use these calls, which are faster:

> [InitializeCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683472(VS.85).aspx)
>
> [EnterCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683472(VS.85).aspx)
>
> [LeaveCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683472(VS.85).aspx)
>
> [DeleteCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682552(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The following funcs will probably be what you want, they are all documented on MSDN.

```
CreateMutex(...)
WaitForSingleObject(...)
ReleaseMutex(...)
```